Seleniumbase Chrome 127 "search engine is needed" problem
In the Chrome version 127 always get a chrome popup with search engine is needed and I have to choose.
I use seleniumbase but cannot hide it, disable or click. So ruin all my process...
I saw some solution in selenium:
options.addArguments("--disable-search-engine-choice-screen")
But it is difficult to add to Seleniumbase.
So I need this but for seleniumbase version!
Has sy a solution?
Thank you in advance!

it's not likely that this prompt would hinder your tests at all.  Are you sure that's the problem here?

yes. so i know that is for selenium and not for seleniumbase. I would like to produce the same but for seleniumbase

That option was recently added to SeleniumBase default options. Upgrade your version of SeleniumBase and try again.

You have to add the following option:
Driver(
chromium_arg=""--disable-search-engine-choice-screen"
)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
